# Hide text of search box in sharepoint

Tags: search, sharepoint, hide

I want to hide the text of a searchtextbox, but I don't know how to do it. I'm a Sharepoint noob, so I think it is easy to do it but I don't know how... I put my code below, hope it helps:

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaSiteLogo" runat="server" BlockElement="True">
<!--search-->
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaPlaceHolderSearchArea" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-mpSearchBox ms-floatRight" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
        <div id="searchInputBox">
            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementById('SmallSearchInputBox').placeholder = 'Ex: SMS1234';
                    document.getElementById('SmallSearchInputBox').value = 'Ex: SMS1234';
                }, 800);//time to wait for in ms
            </script>
        </div>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" CssClass="ms-siteicon-a" ID="x36d5bee949a7480783b3afc048c15598" NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/Pages/Inicio.aspx">
    <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage name="onetidHeadbnnr0" runat="server" CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" ID="x74bbee6762f840edad4fe46f496d8c78" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png"></SharePoint:SiteLogoImage>
</SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
```

I follow [this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179971/change-the-placeholder-text-for-the-find-a-file-search-box-for-document-librarie), but this solution didn't work for me and It doesn't change the text of the textbox:

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The control ID will change as page inherit, for example:
[image]

Try to use jQuery regex selector, for example:

```
$('div[id*="SmallSearchInputBox"]')
```